# Impossible to solve Sharepoint dropdown behavior

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am currently experiencing some very weird dropdown menu behavior in Sharepoint.

## Summary of the issue

Dropdowns do not appear if I Ctrl+R to refresh the page. Dropdown items do appear if I click into the address bar and click enter. Also, if I make the page hit a breakpoint in developer tools while loading, the dropdown will work even when I hit Ctrl+R.

## How to reproduce the issue:

- Go to the website: http://www.jdaihelpdesk.org/default.aspx
- Mouse over one of the menu items at the top, dropdown items **will** appear.
- However, if you hit Ctrl+R to reload the page, when you mouse over one of the menu items, the dropdown **will no longer** appear.
- Even weirder, if you open up developer tools and put a breakpoint on line 5 of the resource file titled http://www.jdaihelpdesk.org/ScriptResource.axd?d=mp6tevUL8oeNESOYJzVjF4zt3gpf2XdWLbE3BbLBQDYBVZVAQp00gRgopkUa1x9lC9s-iuzbDatvYvVbz7xnHLXzyr_vbt6Y91YZqrMVq_6N-PshJk3rZnu9fGlYq2Z8x9XfJo4ZhLF5WQffpPe1KcOEZvI1&t=2e2045e2
  , hit Ctrl+R to refresh the page, after hitting continue, the menu item **will** work.

So it's like there's something to do with when resources are getting loaded or something but that's just a guess after hours of looking at this issue.

What's also weird to me is that hitting Ctrl+R will cause the dropdowns to not appear but clicking in the address bar and hitting Enter to load the page, the dropdowns will appear.

If anybody has any insights that would be awesome!

Comment: It works fine for me - running chrome